# android back from background to foreground

Tags: android, android-intent

Application starts intent for web browser or email:

```
 String url = "http://google.com/";
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
```

When application starts web browser and I back my application from background to foreground, application wont response. It wont back to activity which lunched web browser. Nowhere in activity is finish().
I don't receive any error in Android Studio about this problem. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: There's not enough information in this question to help you. Check your logcat for exceptions, crashes or other information. Don't filter the logcat as you might miss important information.

Comment: Kindly add some additional info